# Getting Network Request Failed Error in Expo android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Getting Network Request Failed Error in Expo android, But all api's is working fine in IOS devices.

- Error getting in both Emulator and After Build for android.
- The Error persist for all api call's, including mine and other third party api's.

  My API:-

  `https://api.mydomain.com/`

  And other third party also like:-

  `https://2factor.in/API/----`

It is Working fine in previos versions of expo, but now i am using **expo@49** for my application.